# How to solve this tricky equation?

Tags: equation-solving

The following equation $${\left( {\frac {x}{2017}}-a \right)  \left( {\frac {x}{a}}-2017
 \right) ^{-1}}={ \left( {\frac {x}{a}}-2017 \right)  \left( {\frac {
x}{2017}}-a \right) ^{-1}}
  $$
in $x$ was asked in a school math olympiad (8th grade). It is clear there is no solution if $a \neq 2017$ or $a \neq -2017$. If $a=2017$ or $a=-2017$ respectively, then each complex number but $2017^2$ or $-2017^2$ respectively is its solution.

Here is my try to solve it with Mathematica:

```
Solve[((1/2017)*x - a)/(x/a - 2017) == (x/a - 2017)/((1/2017)*x - a),x]
```

> {}

and

```
Reduce[((1/2017)*x - a)/(x/a - 2017) == (x/a - 2017)/((1/2017)*x - a), x]
```

> a == -2017 || a == 2017

The question arises: how to obtain the correct answer in Mathematica?

Addition. Another casuistic equation is as follows.

```
Reduce[Abs[1/2017*x - a]/(x/a - 2017) ==  Abs[x/a - 2017]/((1/2017)*x - a), x, Reals]
```

> (a == -2017 && x == -4068289) || a == 2017

The above answer is not correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. `Solve[]` correctly identifies no solution, and `Reduce[]` (as it does) ignores the removable discontinuity.

Comment: @Feyre: You wrote " Solve[] correctly identifies no solution". But there is a lot of solutions if $a=2017$ or $a=-2017$. A conditional expression is expected as an answer, not $\{\}$.

Comment: `Solve[((((x/2017) - a)/(x/a - 2017) - (x/a - 2017)/((x/2017) - 
         a)) /. {x -> 2017^2}) == 0]` returns `{{a -> -2017}, {a -> 2017}}` so `Solve[]` also skips the discontinuity. I thinks `Solve[]` just fails in the first instance, though it's weird no warning is returned.

Comment: @Feyre: Your Solve[((((x/2017) - a)/(x/a - 2017) - (x/a - 2017)/((x/2017) - a)) /. {x -> 2017^2}) == 0] solves a different problem than a problem under consideration. Therefore, your conclusion is not based.

Comment: `Eliminate[((1/2017)*x - a)/(x/a - 2017) == (x/a - 2017)/((1/2017)*x - 
     a), x]` gives `a^2==4068289`

Comment: @Rolf Mertig: You solve a different problem from the problem under consideration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs for [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html): "`Solve` gives generic solutions only."  And the returned empty solution is generically correct.

From the docs for [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html): "The result of `Reduce[expr,vars]` always describes exactly the same mathematical set as `expr`."

This is not strictly true. For instance, `1/(x/y)` evaluates automatically to the generically equivalent `y/x`, independently of `Reduce` or `Solve`.  But even inside `Reduce`, a similar transformation must take place in the following, since division by `y` is indicated in the formula which should exclude `y == 0`:

```
Reduce[1/(1 - x/y) == 0, x]
(*  y == 0 && x != 0  *)
```

Well, somehow [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) manages to be a bit more careful (although I don't think anything that lets `1/(x/y)` evaluate can save that case).

```
eqn = ((1/2017)*x - a)/(x/a - 2017) == (x/a - 2017)/((1/2017)*x - a);

Reduce[eqn && FunctionDomain[eqn /. Equal -> Subtract, x], {x}]
(*  (a == -2017 && 4068289 + x != 0) || (a == 2017 && -4068289 + x != 0)  *)
```

Comment: You saw the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
FullSimplify[((1/2017)*x - a)/(x/a - 2017) == (x/a - 2017)/((1/2017)*x - a)]
```

yields

```
a == 4068289/a
```

Solving that yields `{{a->2017},{a-> -2017}}`.

Simply doing `((1/2017)*x - a)/(x/a - 2017) == (x/a - 2017)/((1/2017)*x - a) /. {{a->2017},{a-> -2017}} // FullSimplify` yields `{True,True}`, indicating the equation is true independent of `x`.

Comment: Sorry, this is not it at all.